# Exception Error Navigating To UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, segue

Firstly I just want to thank this community for creating the best support site on the web.  My situation is that I already have an app that works with a navigation controller and 2 view controllers.  I did the following:

1. Created a new UIButton on one of the view controllers.
2. Dragged a segue link (Push) from the button to the new view controller.
3. Added a new class of SupportViewController.
4. Set the Custom Class in the new view controller of SupportViewController.

When I click the button (regardless of whether I set up the segue as push or modal), I get:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SupportViewController setCelebrityInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff01adf30d0'

Clearly I am missing something, I just need somebody elses expertise to point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Show the code in your `prepareForSegue` method and where the `celebrityInfo` property/methods are declared.

Comment: search for CelebrityInfo in your code, and see whats going on

Comment: When I search the project, I don't even see setCelebrityInfo shown in results - where is it getting that from?

Comment: do you have a property named celebrityInfo anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I created a button on another view controller and that links to the new view controller without issue, so closing this as I used a workaround.  Thanks to everyone who contributed, even if you did resort to name calling.

Comment: We should step and go down:)))

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax again make sure setCelebrityInfo takes parameters. If not get rid of final ":"  If we have a method declared as -(void) setCelebrityInfo {} we don't need to use : when calling it. If we have something like (type) method (param) we are using :. I hope that simple example helps you. Make sure you have such method defined and implemented  in your target view controller (code).

Comment: When I search the project, I don't even see setCelebrityInfo shown in results - where is it getting that from?

Comment: I think you can easy search for addTarget

Comment: You provided an answer which I was using to try to resolve my issue,  then you change to cussing me out, how is that constructive?  If everyone here knew how things work, what would be the point of this site?  I didn't copy/paste from another project (maybe I would have had more success if I did).  I am using Xcode 7.2 under El Capitan.  That's all.

Comment: Clean your build, and retry. I think those are from a previous build (leftovers). Also clean derived data. Also remove app from device  Then do a clean build  run and whatever. This is the way .